# Approximating sphere with fixed radius to a set of points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I would like to find the center of a sphere of fixed radius that best approximates a set of points.

I want to minimize:

$$E(C) = \sum (|C - X_i|^2 - r^2)^2 $$

Where $X_i$ is the point $i$.
Deriving with respect to $C$ and setting to zero we get:

$$0 = 4 \sum (|C - X_i|^2 - r^2)(C - X_i)$$

If we call $\Delta_i = C - X_i$, we have

$$0 = \sum (\Delta_i^t \Delta_i - r^2) \Delta_i$$

How can I find $C \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that that the above equation equals zero?

In the geometric tools library the [approximation of a sphere without a fixed radius](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LeastSquaresFitting.pdf) is explained.

Comment: You refer to both "with fixed radius" and "without a fixed radius". Is that deliberate? Is your definition of E missing a square? What are you differentiating with respect to?

Comment: I forgot a square in $E(C)$. I'm interested in the case with fixed radius. I'm differentiating with respect to $C$.

Comment: $C$ is a 3D vector. So be careful when you say you are "differentiating with respect to $C$". You have to differentiate with respect to the indiviual components of $C$. Your formula might be considered correct, but make sure you understand which parts of the formula are vectors and which are scalars. Your equation is cubic in the components of $C$. This means that there is probably no nice and easy solution you can write down as a formula (though a computer program should have no trouble to find a solution numerically).

Comment: The link you posted deals with a slightly different function $E$, which leads to a quadratic condition, which is much easier to solve. So if possible, you should go with that.